# Calculating words per minute in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with this calculation. However, I have done the code but my client says the calculation is wrong. he says (I did a test read for 3 seconds and the WPM was 298 it should have been like 11,000 wpm, the paragraph words were 290)

here is the live demo url, please select a paragraph and start it, 
http://www.freereadingtest.com/

Here is the code

```
var numWordsInText, myTimer, startTime, wpm;
function SetNumWordsInText(b) {
    s = b;
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n");
    numWordsInText = s.split(" ").length
}

function updateWPM() {
    if (wpm = (new Date).getTime() - startTime) wpm /= 1E3, wpm = numWordsInText / wpm, wpm *= 60;
    5E4 > wpm && (document.getElementById("wpm1").innerHTML = wpm.toFixed(0));
    myTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        updateWPM()
    }, 500)
}
```

Comment: I can't dream of anybody here that is going to run some quiz on a 3rd party site before being able to help you with an answer. Provide a _minimal working code snippet_ within the question, reproducing the issue described.

Comment: thank you, I have added a direct paragraph link, so there is no quiz to be taken.

Comment: **Provide a _minimal working code snippet_ within the question, reproducing the issue described**, not an external link. And if you don't understand what that mean, read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Honestly, I make no sense at all out of the demo.  How can you reasonably give a running total when you don't know the number of words read until it's completed?  I also make little sense out of your code.  If you're just looking to calculate WPM, it should be a simple formula based on number of words, start time and end time: `wpm = nbrOfWords / minutes`, equivalent to `wpm = nbrOfWords / ((endTime - startTime) / 60000)`.

Answer (score 2):

So, I tried it here with random text. I got the total seconds that it took to read (`const seconds = 3`) and used your `setNumWordsInText()`. I then divided the words by the time in seconds to see how many words per second. Then, I multiplied by 60 to get the number of words that it would be in one minute. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

```
const setNumWordsInText = b => {
  let s = b
  s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "")
  s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ")
  s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n")
  return s.split(" ").length
}

const updateWPM = (t, w) => (w / t) * 60

const txt = "Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet rump t-bone andouille, reprehenderit veniam sausage burgdoggen tri-tip pork chop shoulder. In labore pork leberkas bacon, dolor fugiat sunt sint excepteur ball tip landjaeger ut corned beef. T-bone in magna, consectetur do sirloin culpa elit labore meatloaf quis pariatur. Magna veniam capicola consequat, drumstick filet mignon excepteur. Hamburger pork consequat incididunt aliqua tongue cupim nulla burgdoggen leberkas sirloin."

const numWordsInText = setNumWordsInText(txt)
const seconds = 3
const wpm = updateWPM(seconds, numWordsInText)
console.log(wpm)
```